gsap.from() method not working correctly in Next.js environment
This code isn't working as intended. I can see the contents of the refs, which are p and h3 tags, flash up for a second when refreshing the page but then they are not animating. The gsap.to() method is working perfectly fine though.
I am in a Next.js environment with React 18.
const middleRef = useRef(null);
  const refs = useRef([]);
  refs.current = [];

  const addtoRefs = (el) => {
    if (el && !refs.current.includes(el)) {
      refs.current.push(el);
    }
  };

 useLayoutEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: middleRef.current, // ref to middle section,
        start: "top 20%", 
        end: "bottom+=20% center",
      },
    });

if (refs.current.length > 0) {
      timeline.from(refs.current, {
        yPercent: 140,
        stagger: 0.1,
      });
}

I was trying to animate the refs with the gsap.from() method but that didnt work.

flash up for a second when refreshing the page but then they are not animating. What do you mean by this? Flash up? Can you make gif or CodePen?

did you tried @gsap/react and useGsap() ?

using useGsap() solved the issue.
